# if(x>2): print(x) but 1 is printed do you know why? (in python, django view)

Tags: python, django

code

```
for sn in skil_note:
    if(sn.category.id > int(ca_num) & sn.category.id != 99):  # ca num = 2
        print("sn.category.id : ", sn.category.id)
    else:
        print("haha: " , sn.category.id)
```

result

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
ca_num :  2
sn.category.id :  89
sn.category.id :  89
sn.category.id :  89
sn.category.id :  1
sn.category.id :  1
haha:  2
haha:  2
haha:  2
haha:  2
haha:  2
sn.category.id :  3
sn.category.id :  3
sn.category.id :  3
sn.category.id :  3
sn.category.id :  3
sn.category.id :  3
sn.category.id :  5
sn.category.id :  5
sn.category.id :  5
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  6
sn.category.id :  8
sn.category.id :  8
sn.category.id :  1
sn.category.id :  10
sn.category.id :  10
sn.category.id :  10
```

If you know the reason, thanks
`2> 1`, but if you can tell me why `1` is output, thank you
Is the if statement wrong?

Should I compare in another way?
Is there a problem with the format of the for or if statements?

Comment: Please do not use `&`.

Comment: thanks i will keep in mind ~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do (note the ***and***):

```py
for sn in skil_note:
    if(sn.category.id > int(ca_num) and sn.category.id != 99):  # ca num = 2
        print("sn.category.id : ", sn.category.id)
    else:
        print("haha: " , sn.category.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statement, use `and` instead of `&` :

```py
if a and b:
    ...
```

While `and` is a logical operator that is used in boolean operations to perform a "logical AND",
`&` is a bitwise operator that performs a "bitwise AND".